# Application for visitor visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I have applied for my mum to visit me and they refused citing paragraph 4.2 of Appendix 5, 'you state that you retired bla bla bla, but documents do not demonstrate this'. What shall I do? They have accepted that I do have sufficient funds to support her etc.

Comment: We see many similar questions on TSE. If the suggested duplicate doesn’t answer your own question, please upload a copy of the refusal notice with personal information blanked out and edit your original question to state exactly what your specific problem is